# Вывести имена в алфавитном порядке на каждый лист в excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, phpexcel

В общем я пытаюсь сгенерировать ексель файл с именами из базы данных. У меня получилось распечатать и создать листы с каждой буквой алфавита. Но вот  именами проблема. Каким способом можно сделать это?

Вот что у мен имеется:

```
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
{
    $Letter='B';
    $Number=2;  
    $F = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($i); //Setting index when creating
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $F->setCellValue('A1', "Username")
      ->setCellValue('B1', "Project")   
      ->setCellValue('C1', "Processes");

    $request="SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%'";
    $result= $conn->query($request);//get the result (ressource)          

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {      
            $username=$row["username"];
            $F->setCellValue('A'.$Number, ' '.$username.' ');
            $F->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(20);
            $F->getColumnDimension($Letter)->setWidth(30);
            ++$Number;
        }
    } else 
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }                                   
    $F->setTitle(chr($i));      
}
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

проблему решил путем удаления `if statement`

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
{
    $Letter='B';
    $Number=2;  
    $F = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($i); //Setting index when creating
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $F->setCellValue('A1', "Username")
      ->setCellValue('B1', "Project")   
      ->setCellValue('C1', "Processes");

    $request="SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%'";
    $result= $conn->query($request);//get the result (ressource)          

        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {      
            $username=$row["username"];
            $F->setCellValue('A'.$Number, ' '.$username.' ');
            $F->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(20);
            $F->getColumnDimension($Letter)->setWidth(30);
            ++$Number;
        }                               
    $F->setTitle(chr($i));      
}
```